# How to add a page counter to a report?

Tags: visual-studio, report

I am making a report for labels in Visual Studio. One of the parameters that the user enters is "label count," which produces the number of labels that the user chooses. The labels should be identical except for one textbox that reads "LABEL COUNT: X OF Y," where Y is the "label count" and X is the current label number, incrementing from 1 to Y. How can I implement this?

Comment: Try posting some code showing what you have tried already

Comment: So far I've tried creating another report with a subreport embedded in a table and linked to my main report. It was a really roundabout way that I couldn't get working quite right and was hoping that there's something more straightforward I could try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. This can be solved by inserting the contents of the label into a rectangle and then inserting that rectangle into a table. You will need to modify the code section of the table so that it creates a new page for each increment to the labelCount parameter. Then just insert a footer to the report to display the page count using the builtin page number variables.